Access Additional Order Details In Shopify Checkout UI Extension
I’m working on a Checkout UI Extension for the Order Status page on a Shopify site. It is intended to be a private custom extension. It uses the target:
purchase.thank-you.block.render

While the Order is generally available, the data is limited to an ID and name. There are other limited pieces of data available via the StandardAPI, but the data I am looking for is a custom metafield I store for every order called estimated_ship_date. This field is updated by a Flow at order creation and nightly so I can’t use a cart attribute.
I’ve scoured the docs and I can’t seem to find any way to access this data for use on the Order Status page.
I’ve tried setting the meta fields in the .toml like this:
[[extensions.metafields]]
namespace = "custom"
key = "estimated_ship_date"

But the docs seem to make it clear we don’t have access to metafields for Orders.
I find it hard to believe that with all the other data extensions do have access to, that we wouldn’t have accsss to this, so I must be missing something.
